# Kubectl apply Deployment to specified Node Group - AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created multiple stacks (node groups) within my **EKS cluster**, and each group runs on a **different instance type** (for example, one group runs on GPU instances). I have added an entry in *mapRoles* of *aws-auth-cm.yaml* file for each of the node groups. Now I would like to deploy some *Deployments* on another. The deployment files look something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: component-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: component-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: d1
          image: docker-container
          ports:
            - containerPort: 83
```

The documentation shows that I can run the standard command **kubectl apply**. Is there any way to specify the group? Maybe something like

> kubectl apply -f server-deployment.yaml -group node-group-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly something that you mentioned doesn't exist, but you can read about [Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) and it should solve your problem.

TL;DR you have to add labels or use existing labels on nodes and use these labels to assign pods to correct nodes.

Assuming you have label `beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=highmem`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: component-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: component-1
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/instance-typ
                operator: In
                values:
                - highmem
      containers:
        - name: d1
          image: docker-container
          ports:
            - containerPort: 83
```

Comment: I found that the Affinity is in the wrong location. It should be under the spec in the template.

`template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {appName}
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key:  {labelKey}
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      -  {labelValue}# Deploy only to this Labeled Node Group`

Comment: On AKS  (Azure) I can  use `nodeSelector` to reference a node pool, which allows me to direct applications to specific node groups (each of a different instance type). Ideally the same mechanism would be available for EKS on AWS, however I'm not finding any documentation on this - specifically the label to be used for a given node group. Either it's not there by default and I have to label this using my own method, or it is but not clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) to ensure that your pods end up on the right nodes. When you have heterogeneous nodes, this is good practice.

For example, in my deployment, we have 2 classes of nodes, ones which have NVMe SSD attached and ones which don't. They're both tainted differently and the deployments that run on top specify tolerations which ensure that they end up only on the nodes that have that particular taint.

For example, the node would have:

```
spec:
    ...
    taints:
    - effect: NoSchedule
      key: role
      value: gpu-instance
```

and a pod that must schedule on one of those nodes must have:

```
spec:
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoSchedule
      key: role
      operator: Equal
      value: gpu-instance
```

Once you have this setup, you can just do a regular `kubectl apply` and pods will get targeted onto nodes correctly.
Note that this is a more flexible approach than node selectors and labels because it can give you more fine grained control and configurable eviction behavior.

Comment: if this approach is taken then nothing has to be specified in the Deployment yaml file?

Comment: You do have to specify the toleration under the pod template inside the deployment YAML.

Answer (score 3):

nodeSelector should work for this as well, as long as you have labeled your Nodes

Examples and more info here: https://eksworkshop.com/beginner/140_assigning_pods/node_selector/ and here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector

Answer (score 3):

EKS automatically adds a label to nodes in a node group and you can use this to choose which node group your pod is assigned to.

To accomplish this with the yaml you provide above, extend it like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: component-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: component-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: d1
          image: docker-container
          ports:
            - containerPort: 83
      nodeSelector:
        eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: node-group-1
```

(I've only added the last two lines.)

For more details on the general mechanism, see the links that Vladimir provides in his answer.